# How to generate the spectrogram of a wav file in Matlab with frequency on the x-axis

Tags: android, matlab, audio, spectrogram

As part of a research project, I would like to analyze a sound file by generating it's spectrogram.

I have been able to successfully generate the spectrogram of the wave file in matlab with frequency on the y-axis and the time on the x-axis. I would however, like to generate the spectrogram with the frequency on the x-axis and the time on the y-axis. How can this be done?

I have searched through stack and have not found any accepted answers.

My code which generates the spectrogram with the frequency on the y-axis and the time on the x-axis (Matlab code):

```
[song, fs] = wavread('filename.wav');
windowSize = 256;
windowOverlap = [];
freqRange = 0:300;
spectrogram(song, windowSize, windowOverlap, freqRange, fs, 'yaxis');
```

I changed the parameter 'yaxis' in the function spectrogram to 'xaxis' and the frequency is now on the x-axis with time on the y-axis. But, I get a spectrogram different from what is generated from a reliable source.

Here is the spectrogram that I generate - [image: spectrogram]

The spectrogram generated from a reliable source (I don't have the code).

[image: reliable_spectrogram]

Moreover, the color scheme is different in both the spectrograms. And my recording is 50 seconds long whereas the time displayed on the label is 9 seconds. How can I resolve these issues?

My end task is to be able to generate the spectrogram on an android device (probably using the GraphView library in android). So I would have to write code to generate the spectrogram in Java.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I submitted a long-winded answer using custom code, but I think the main problem is you’re using way too small `windowSize`. 256 samples even at 8 KHz is just 30 milliseconds. Try enough samples for 1–3 seconds, that’s closer to what the second “authoritative” spectrogram uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preface

Sorry, I don’t have whichever -toolbox- that Mathworks puts [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) in, but here’s some code that I put in the public domain that does the job for me.

It’s more hands-on than `spectrogram` but has many of the latter’s features, as I’ll demonstrate using the `handel` audio clip that comes with Matlab (‘Hallelujah!’).

## Setup

I won’t assume you’re familiar with git or Matlab namespaces.

1. Create a directory called `+arf` somewhere in your Matlab path (e.g., `~/Documents/MATLAB` or even your current code directory).
2. Download [`stft.m`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/master/%2Barf/stft.m) and put it in `+arf/`.
3. Also download [`partition.m`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/master/%2Barf/partition.m) into `+arf/`.

This creates an `arf` [namespace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) inside which are the `arf.stft` and `arf.partition` functions (the latter is used by `arf.stft`).

## Code

```
clearvars

% Load data: this is an audio clip built into Matlab.
handel = load('handel');
% To hear this audio clip, run the following:
% >> soundsc(handel.y, handel.Fs)

% STFT parameters.
% 1000 samples is roughly 1/8th of a second. A reasonable chunk size.
samplesPerChunk = 1000;
% Overlap a lot between chunks to see a smooth STFT.
overlapSamples = round(samplesPerChunk * 0.9);

% Generate STFT
[stftArr, fVec, tVec] = arf.stft(handel.y, ...
                                 samplesPerChunk, ...
                                 'noverlap', overlapSamples, ...
                                 'fs', handel.Fs);

% Plot results
figure('color', 'white');
imagesc(fVec / 1e3, tVec, 20 * log10(abs(stftArr)).');
axis xy
colorbar
xlabel('frequency (KHz)')
ylabel('time (s)')
caxis(max(caxis) - [40 0])
title('`handel` spectrogram via STFT, top 40 dB')
```

The code above

1. loads the `handel` audio clip that’s packaged into Matlab (this is a nine-second clip from George Frideric Handel’s *Messiah*),
2. defines some parameters for the STFT,
3. evaluates the STFT with `arf.stft()`, and
4. plots the STFT.

Hint: after you run the code above, or just that `load` line, you can listen to the original clip with `soundsc(handel.y, handel.Fs)`.

## Results

[image: STFT of handel Hallelujah clip]

In the spectrogram, you can clearly see the first two long Hallelujah’s, then the two shorter ones, and then finally the last long one. Time runs along the y-axis as you wished.

The code demonstrates how to specify the chunk length (here, 1000 samples, or ≈⅛ seconds) and the amount of overlap (90% of the chunk length, so 900 samples of overlap). Note:

- Larger chunk length will result in less resolution in time (but greater resolution in frequency).
- The less overlap, the more jaggedy and less smooth the STFT appears along time (and the less computational/memory overhead you pay). The amount of overlap must be between 0 (no overlap between chunks) and `chunk size - 1`.

If you just play around with the chunk length, you’ll get a feel for the main knob the STFT gives you to tune. Usually one picks overlap between 25% or 50% of chunk size for reasonably-smooth spectrograms without a huge amount of computational overhead.

N.B. You can increase smoothness along the *frequency* dimension by passing in an extra argument to `arf.stft`, specifically, `arf.stft( ..., 'nfft', 2^nextpow2(samplesPerChunk * 8))`. This explicitly sets the number of frequency bins to create (eventually, an FFT of this size is evaluated). The default is equivalent to `2^nextpow2(samplesPerChunk)`, so multiplying it by eight will upsample the spectrum for each chunk eight-fold.

Comment: Let me try this out today and see if I can mark this as the correct answer.